# Как реализовать плавное перемещение объекта?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Нужно реализовать плавное перемещение объекта из одной точки в другую. Сейчас есть:

**Инициализация перемещения:**

1. Сохранение финальной позиции.
2. Сохранение времени перемещения.
3. Расчет и сохранение дистанции между точками начала и завершения перемещения.
4. Расчет и сохранения вектора направления движения.

**Реализация перемещения:**

1. Каждый шаг таймера объект смещается в нужном направлении на расстояние, равное общей дистанции, деленной на общее время перемещения.
2. При достижении финальной позиции объект останавливается.

Такой вариант работает, но перемещение получается линейным, объект, будто бы, бьется о прозрачную стенку в конце движения. А здесь не так:

https://jsfiddle.net/14wc6hqb/3/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div').animate({left: '+=100'}, 700, 'swing', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('div').css({left: 0});
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

При таком перемещении его скорость плавно возрастает и потом плавно уменьшается перед остановкой. Какими алгоритмами можно достичь подобного эффекта?

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте т.н. s-образную кривую перемещения (A-Y)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прощу всего сделать это, если профиль скорости имеет форму трапеции - т.е. сначала скорость линейно растёт до некоторого предела, потом остаётся постоянной, в конце линейно падает до нуля (A-B-C-D)

Рассчитать профиль скорости для достижения конечной точки за заданное время можно, задавая нужные величины - это может быть ускорение и предел скорости, или временные параметры участков ускорения и замедления. Главное - чтобы площадь под трапецией на графике скорость-время получилась равной заданной дистанции.

Answer (score 1):

Вриант с резким началом и плавным ококчанием.

`animate` абстрагирует работу с `requestAnimationFrame`.

`animation.getPos(t)` вычисляет полную позицию на текущий момент
(работаем не с разницей на шаге, и не зависим от частоты шага).

`getProgress` линейно меняется от 1 до 0.
`Math.pow(getProgress(t), unsmooth)` меняется от 1 до 0, но уже не линейно.
Это выражение можно дальше изменять для достижения более сложного эффекта.

```js
function createAnimation({startPos,targetPos,startTime,targetTime,unsmooth}){
    const getFinished = t => targetTime < t
    const getProgress = t => getFinished(t) ? 0 : (targetTime-t)/(targetTime-startTime)
    const getPos = t => targetPos - (targetPos-startPos) * Math.pow(getProgress(t), unsmooth)
    return {getPos,getFinished}
}

function animate(callback){
    const iter = () => {
        const t = Date.now()
        if(callback(t)) requestAnimationFrame(iter)
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(iter)
}

const div = document.createElement('button')
div.style = "position: absolute; background-color: red; left: 50px"
div.textContent = "TEST"
document.body.appendChild(div)

div.onclick = ev => {
  const startTime = Date.now()
  const targetTime = startTime + 2000
  const startPos = parseInt(div.style.left)
  const targetPos = startPos + 200
  const unsmooth = 4
  const animation = createAnimation({startPos,targetPos,startTime,targetTime,unsmooth})
  animate(t=>{
    div.style.left = animation.getPos(t) + "px"
    return !animation.getFinished(t)
  })
}
```