# Как правильно использовать easing-функцию для перемещения?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, анимация

Подскажите, как изменить значение параметра, используя `easing`-функции. К примеру, для перемещения объекта. Перед началом перемещения я сохраняю такие данные:

```
Время анимации
Дистанция, которую нужно пройти
Расстояние одного шага (дистанция / время)
Количество шагов
Направление перемещения
```

Затем для линейного перемещения я в таймере перемещаю объект в нужном направлении на расстояние одного шага.

Для использования `easing`-функции я рассчитываю дополнительный параметр `[0..1]`, который содержит процентное отношение пройденного пути к общей дистанции, и затем передаю этот параметр в функцию. Сама функция - `InOutQuad` - выглядит так:

```
x < 0.5 ? 2 * x * x : -1 + (4 - 2 * x) * x
```

В результате возвращаемое функцией значение я умножаю на длину одного шага, - думаю, что по логике это коэффициент, который изменяет размер шага так, чтобы общая пройденная дистанция из суммы всех шагов осталась неизменной. То есть, в начале пути объект двигается медленно, а в середине компенсирует это более быстрым перемещением.

Объект не доходит даже до середины пути и останавливается. Что я делаю не так?

---

Привожу свой код:

```
t = stepNum / animTime;
easing = t < 0.5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;

object.move(angle, stepDist * easing);

stepNum++;
```

Функция `move()` перемещает объект на заданное расстояние в заданном направлении. Я сам пока склоняюсь ко мнению, что такой метод перемещения конфликтует с идеей `eeasing`-функции, где, насколько я понял, перед началом анимации должно сохраняться начальное значение параметра, и потом каждый шаг анимации к нему должно прибавляться значение `dist * easing`. То есть, общая дистанция, умноженная на возвращенное значение.

Если так, подскажите, как можно подстроить эту функцию под такой метод перемещения.

Comment: `дополнительный параметр [0..1]` ... `я умножаю на длину одного шага` то есть вы замедляете объект

Comment: @tym32167, я так понимаю, что результатом этой функции объект должен замедляться в начале пути и ускоряться в середине, компенсируя это замедление.

Comment: Приведённая формула - одна из реализаций S-образной кривой скорости. А вот насчёт `возвращаемое функцией значение я умножаю на длину одного шага,` -  код покажите

Comment: @MBo, изменил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведённая формула - одна из реализаций S-образной кривой скорости, о которой я говорил в [прошлой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177782). Формула показывает, на каком **расстоянии** будет находиться точка в зависимости от времени. А вот чтобы рассчитать шаг - нужна скорость, производная от этого перемещения. В данном случае профиль скорости треугольный - скорость линейно растёт до середины пути, потом линейно падает до нуля.

```
V = 4 * t в первой половине
Vh = 2 в середине
V =  2 - 2 * t  во второй половине
```

Почему такие коэффициенты в easing функции и для скорости? Чтобы обеспечить площадь под кривой скорости (интеграл скорости по времени),  равную единице (т.е. весь путь пройден за время t=1).

Имея готовую easing-функцию, Вы можете рассчитывать **абсолютное положение** точки в каждый момент времени, т.е она даёт не шаг, а положение. Если есть метод для абсолютного позиционирования - вычисляйте

```
object.moveToPoint(angle, fulldistance * easing);
```

Если только относительный сдвиг - то считайте шаг  как разность между двумя easing-значениями для последовательных моментов времени.

```
lasteas = 0
...
easing = t < 0.5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
object.move(angle, fulldistance * (easing - lasteas));
lasteas = easing
```

При необходимости можно опираться и на скорость для расчёта шага, но есть некоторые подводные камни - при ступенчатом движении суммарный результат может несколько отличаться от единицы.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли.