# Как задать нелинейную интерполяцию движения обьекта в SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, glsurfaceview

Нужно написать игру на Surface View и не понимаю как задать интерполяцию как допустим в css ease или SmoothStep в Юнити (нужна нелинейная интерполяция). Есть какие-либо формулы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожелания довольно абстрактные, но вот возможный вариант:

Вначале объект двигается с постоянным ускорением до достижения максимальной скорости

```
v = a * t
```

Затем движение на максимальной скорости. Если целевое расстояние слишком мало, максимальная скорость может быть не достигнута

Затем торможение с тем же ускорением

```
 v = vmax - a * t
```

Кривая пройденного пути (s-образная) будет выглядеть как кусок параболы, затем наклонная прямая, потом другая парабола

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. И [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1179456/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-easing-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/1179547#1179547) ещё посмотрите